# Insert multi-line JSON into YAML

Tags: yq

Have a **ConfigMap.yaml** file that looks like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: someCF
data:
  appsettings.k8s.json: |
   {
    "Logging": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft": "Warning",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
       }
     }
   }
```

Also have another JSON file named JSON1 that I need to put into data.appsettings.k8s.json:

```
    {
    "Logging": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Full",
        "Microsoft": "Error",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
       }
     }
   }
```

How to change JSON in **data.appsettings.k8s.json** so it will look like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: someCF
data:
  appsettings.k8s.json: |
    {
      "Logging": {
        "LogLevel": {
          "Default": "Full",
          "Microsoft": "Error",
          "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pretty-print the JSON file and pass that as an argument to `yq`. Since [mikefarah/yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq) allows you to update YAML multi-line, you could just do.

The [style](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/operators/style) for the `appsettings.k8s.json` is already at `literal`, so it doesn't have to be modified

```
JSON="$(yq -o=json json_file)" yq '.data."appsettings.k8s.json" = strenv(JSON)' yaml
```

Use the `-i` or `--inplace` flag to update the file inplace. Tested on version `4.25.3`

Comment: Moving to comment because fomatting (sorry)

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can also load the file as a string direct like this:

```
yq '.data."appsettings.k8s.json" = loadstr("json_file")' yaml
```

disclaimer: I wrote yq